# MySQL select with condition on different rows

Tags: mysql

I have a rather specific query that I can't find an answer for (possibly I don't know for which kind of keyword I have to google). Lets say I have a relational table that puts 2 tables into relation. So the table in question is a set of tuple of two foreign ids.
As an easy example, lets assume that the table consists of the two tuples {(1, 3), (1, 4)}
Now the query that I want to do is something like:

```
SELECT id1 FROM table WHERE id2 IN (3) AND id2 IN (4)
```

Obviously there is no such row such that fulfills both conditions. And here is the problem. I want that one row fulfills the first the first condition and another the second while they both should have the same id1 to be in the result. So what I would expect as result would be 1.
In general there can be more than two of these conditions...
I hope this was clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT id1
FROM tab
WHERE id2 IN (3,4)               -- #1 here goes ids
GROUP BY id1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id2) = 2;  -- here goes number of elements from #1
```

Comment: Ok that nearly works. I might've made it not clear enough. The id2sets should be distinct ones. So there must be some id2 from the first set (so ORed) AND some id2 from the second set etc.

So it would still need to be something like
`SELECT si
FROM test123
WHERE pi IN (3) AND pi IN (4)               -- #1 here goes ids
GROUP BY si
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pi) = 2`
which leads to the original problem...
In the end it could have been pi IN (3, 6, 9) AND pi IN (4, 8, 12) or so... I just wanted to keep the exampe simple